# How to verify the 6 digit otp from mysql with php

Tags: php

here is my code for optverify.php if the input number is wrong its redirect to index.php its not giving error.its should give a error for wrong otp but please help me to solve this issue

```
  <?php
 // Create a unique instance of your session variables
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['usr_id']))
        {
            $uid=$_SESSION['usr_id'];
        } else {

            header("Location:login.php");
        }
require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();

if (isset($_POST['verifyotp'])) {
    $otpsms = $_POST['smsotp'];
    $otpemail = $_POST['emailotp'];

    $user = $db->verifyotp($uid);
    if($user){
        $user['smsotp'] = $otpsms;
        $user['emailotp'] = $otpemail;

    header("Location:index.php");

    } else {

        $errormsg = "Invalid otp";
    }

}

?>
```

and my codes for data base  function are below

```
public function verifyotp($uid){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT uid,smsotp,emailotp FROM users WHERE uid = '$uid'");
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $uid);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {

            $stmt->bind_result($uid,$smsotp,$emailotp);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $user = array();
            $user["uid"] = $uid;
            $user["smsotp"] = $smsotp;
            $user["emailotp"] = $emailotp;
            $stmt->close();
            return $user;
     } else 

     {
        return $stmt;
     }

   }
```

Comment: you can pass two arguments to the function verifyotp($uid) like verifyotp($uid, $otp) & check the same in your query along with id using and condition.

Comment: can u pls provide me a example i am little confuse to do it

Comment: its not working same thing is happening its not giving error on invalid otp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested but this should work !! Let me know if this doesn't work. will delete this answer.

**Updated**

Change this `$user = $db->verifyotp($uid);` to `$user = $db->verifyotp($uid, $otpsms, $otpemail);`

then modify your function like below if you are willing to test 3 parameters (1) id (2) smsotp (3) emailotp.

```
public function verifyotp($uid, $sotp, $eotp){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT uid,smsotp,emailotp FROM users WHERE uid = '$uid' And smsotp='$sotp' And emailotp ='$eotp'");
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $uid);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $stmt->bind_result($uid,$smsotp,$emailotp);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $user = array();
            $user["uid"] = $uid;
            $user["smsotp"] = $smsotp;
            $user["emailotp"] = $emailotp;
            $stmt->close();
            return $user;
     } else 

     {
        return $stmt;
     }

   }
```

Comment: ts not working same thing is happening its not giving error on invalid otp

Comment: I have updated answer. changes are in this line. `$user = $db->verifyotp($uid, $otpsms, $otpemail);`